# Total numbers that are smaller than the current number

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to to find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than **nums[i]**, for example:

```
Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
Output: [4,0,1,1,3]
```

This is what I have done:

```
vector<int> smallerNumbersThanCurrent(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int> result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j != i; j++) {
            if (nums[j] < nums[i]) total++;
        }
        result.push_back(total);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The output is:

```
Output: [0,0,1,1,3]
```

The problem is that my program ignore the first element because of my loop, and I dont't know how to fix it, can someone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, that will make my program TLE, I have already tried.

Comment: In that case, you may need a different algorithm. Maybe make a copy of `nums` and sort it. Then use the indexes of the numbers in that vector. Just a thought.

Comment: @hello _"that will make my program TLE"_ Wut plz??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, what do you mean ?

Comment: @hello what **do you** mean?? There's nothing like _"a program gets TLE"_??

Comment: TLE = time limit exceeded. Often used in reference to coding competitions.

Comment: Probably an online judge tells you your algorithm isn't fast enough for the competitive programming challenge. That doesn't mean the algorithm is incorrect, that just means you need a faster algorithm...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ah, that's just crap I am completely ignorant of. Cargo cult programming. I'm not a savage.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I only know the term from other questions on SO.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sure, me either ;-)

Comment: @hello so [edit] & clarify your question accordingly here please!

Comment: It's not clear to me, given your description, why you expect the first element of output to be `4`.  The first element of the input is `8`, and the other elements are `1`, `2` (twice), and `3` which are all less than `8`.   `1+2+2+3` is `8`, and (removing dups) `1+2+3` is `6`.   Neither way of summing gives `4`.    To match your description, the statement (nested in the loops, and `if (nums[j] < nums[i])`) increments `total`, but should add `nums[j]` to `total`.   The inner `for` loop seems to have the wrong end condition too.

Comment: @Peter, the program ask to find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than `nums[i]`, For `nums[0]=8` there exist `4` smaller numbers than it `(1, 2, 2 and 3)`.

Comment: @hello   Oh, okay.   Your use of the word "total" (which implies a summation) misled me.  If you're just trying to count the values less than, "total" is not the word to use.   Anyway, I suspect at least part of your problem is in the end condition of the inner `for` loop.    `j != i`  probably needs to be part of the condition tested by the `if`.

Comment: @hello -- Curious -- [Alternate solution](https://godbolt.org/z/xoooY6o7z).  Will that give a time-limit error?  If it doesn't, that entire code, without comments, is self-documenting, due to the usage of the algorithm functions that are [described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), for example.  Sorting is self-explanatory, the lower_bound explains itself by reading the documentation, the same with `std::distance`.

Comment: @hello you desperately need to edit your question and include your last comment.  That whole part about _find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than `nums[i]`_ is critical information.

Comment: @hello -- Also, the questions asked on those online coding sites almost always have naive, slow solutions that will give a time-limit exceeded error when given extreme amounts of input.  Those questions are carefully crafted this way.  The goal was for you to come up with a totally different approach (sorting, then binary search or using a map) to find the solution.  That requires much more thinking than simple nested `for` loops, which practically a beginner could write up.

Comment: If you wanted to single out one number, this would be a good candidate for [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), but may as well sort it in it current form, take lower bound.

Comment: *"The problem is that my program ignore the first element"* -- if you jump to conclusions like this, you'll blind yourself to other possibilities. Based on this conclusion, reversing the input (`[3,2,2,1,8]`) and ignoring the first element would give `[0,1,1,0,3]` (instead of the correct `[3,1,1,0,4]`). However, your code gives something else: `[0,0,0,0,4]`. I conclude that you have done inadequate testing to draw any conclusions. (Did you try any tests other than what the contest site gave you?)

Comment: Is this this [problem from Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/how-many-numbers-are-smaller-than-the-current-number/). If yes the you should edit] your question to provide that information, since this can be solved in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the inner loop, it shall loop over all elements.
In your case, you only compare with the elements from index 0 to the current i index.
you can change the inner loop stop condition.

```
for (int j = 0; j != nums.size(); j++)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is O(n^2). You can do this is O(n log n) by sorting your list, then the first time each number appears you map it to its index, finally read the original (unsorted list and spit out the map values.

E.g.

Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3]

Sorted Input: 1,2,2,3,8

map built off sorted input: {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>3, 8=>4}

Output: [4,0,1,1,3]

Answer (score 0):

This will take **nlogn** time. This is how you should do it -

```
vector<int> smallerNumbersThanCurrent(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int> result, tempNums=nums;

    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());

    unordered_map<int,int>getIndex;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
       if(getIndex.find(nums[i]) == getIndex.end()) {
           getIndex[nums[i]]=i;
       }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tempNums.size(); i++) {
        
        result.push_back(getIndex[tempNums[i]]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: FYI: `std::unordered_map::insert` does nothing if item already exists, so you can simplify code.